# The resource from “http://localhost:3000/js/extra.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making a app using express and I'm running on this MIME type problem, I don't understand why I'm getting this error because I've set the script type to text/javascript.

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="./js/extra.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>

</head>

<body>
    
</body>


</html>
```

The server file:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening..."));


app.get("/home", (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile("/public/home.html", {root: myPath})
});
```

Comment: what do you receive if you open `http://localhost:3000/js/extra.js` directly in the browser? Javascript or HTML? How is your server even responding to the request for the `extra.js` file? all you have set up is `/home`

Comment: @Bravo when I try to open http://localhost:3000/js/extra.js I get http://localhost:3000/js/extra.js. I didn't know I had to set up something to the extra.js, I thought that I had to just set up the html file.
Do I need a app.get("/js/extra.js", (request, response) => {}) or something like it?

Comment: interesting - so you get the right file - not sure how your server code manages to do that  ... anyway, what mime-type does the server send in the response (check the browser developer tools to inspect that)

Comment: oh, clearly "the server file" isn't your WHOLE server considering `myPath` is never declared anywhere

Comment: oh, right - well, there's the issue - you need to set up express to server files other than `/home`

Comment: `myPath is a local file` - no it's not, it's a (undeclared) *variable* as far as your posted code goes

Comment: @Bravo I set up a express to other server files, and it fixed the problem. 
Thank you for you help and time